# React 16 forces component re-render while returning array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

Assume I have the next piece of code inside the React component

```
removeItem = (item) => {
    this.items.remove(item) // this.items -> mobx array
}

renderItem = (item, index) => {
    var _item = undefined
    switch (item.type) {
        case "header":
            _item = <Header key={item.id} onRemove={() => this.removeItem(item)} />
        // a few more cases
        // note that item.id is unique and static
    }

    // return _item -> works fine
    return [
        _item,
        this.state.suggested
            ? <Placeholder key={-item.id} />
            : null
    ]
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.items.map((item, i) => renderItem(item))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also assume that inside each of item I have a button that triggers onRemove handler with click. And each component has textarea where user can enter his text.

Obviously, when user enters text inside item's textarea, it should be saved until item will be removed.

The problem is when I remove some item, each item that goes after the removed one is being **remounted** (edited for Vlad Zhukov). It happens only when I return an array from renderItem(...) (I mean, when I return only item, this problem doesn't happen).

My question: is this a bug, or it's a feature? And how can I avoid it (desirable without wrapping item and Placeholder with another React child)?

---

**UPDATED**

I tried rewrite `renderItem(...)` the next way:

```
renderItem = (item, index) => {
    var Item = undefined
    switch (item.type) {
        case "header":
            Item = Header
        // a few more cases
        // note that item.id is unique and static
    }

    // return _item -> works fine
    return [
        <Item key={item.id} onRemove={() => this.removeItem(item)} />,
        this.state.suggested
            ? <Placeholder key={-item.id} />
            : null
    ]
}
```

And it still causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerendering is absolutely fine in React and can be considered the main feature. What happens in your case is components **remount** when you make changes to an array of elements when these elements have no `key` props.

[Have a look at this simple example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KyG_exvep3M-t7wIqvV). As you can see rerendering components has no difference but removing the first element will clear values of inputs below.

You've got 2 options:

1. Use a component instead of an array and set `key` to it (see an example). There is really no reason not to.
2. Remove all `key`s. The reason why it works is because React internally already uses keys for elements. However I wouldn't suggest this as it doesn't look reliable enough to me, I'd prefer to control it explicitly.

Comment: Well, actually, both items in returning array have unique static keys, but they're still remounting. Removing from keys deprecated yet - it causes default warnings about missing keys

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance nope, you return an array of arrays, and inner arrays do not (and obviously cannot) have keys.

Comment: Yes, the issue is the nested arrays.

Comment: Well, I supposed that arrays behaviour more smartly... Thought this new feature will help to reduce count of nodes, but with this behaviour in huge amounts of situations this feature becomes useless. Thank you a lot for answer!

Comment: This case is not a problem anymore with React Fragment syntax :)